# How can I get my ServiceInstaller project to include PDB files?

Tags: c#, windows-services, pdb-files

I have a windows service, which when built, includes the PDB files in the output.

I have a Service Installer project, that generates an MSI for installing the service.

I'd like to make it also include PDB files in the output (at least for a particular build configuration, but for all is fine too).

For other project types, you can generally go to Properties and change the settings, however there isn't much on the properties on the ServiceInstaller.

edit:

After some fiddling I've found that I can add the debug symbol output of a project, if I apply it to the service, it seems to include the PDB of the service, which is great. However I was expecting it to include all the pdbs, for all the referenced projects too. Since the service is quite slim and calls into other libraries... Will keep at it...

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I told it to add debug symbols from every project individually by adding them one by one.

This is not ideal, because if projects are added the person adding them will need to remember to add their output to this, whereas if I could get it to just do *.pdb, the target service automatically includes pdb files for all of its referenced projects so that wouldn't be necessary.

However it has done the job for now. I will not mark this answer as accepted in case someone knows of a better way.